# Getting Error while opening excel file which is created by OpenXML SDK 2.5

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have an excel file. I want to cut a row from one sheet to another. Using OpenXML 2.0 I achieved the aim. My excel consists ofa column which calculates the sum

Reference: [Inserting new rows and moving exsisting ones with OpenXML SDK 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453636/inserting-new-rows-and-moving-exsisting-ones-with-openxml-sdk-2-0)

Now the excel is coming out perfectly. Even i have validated excel using productivity tool and there is no error. But when i will open the excel from folder it is giving 2 errors.

1.Error: .... If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes. This message box is appearing all the time.

2. Removed Records: Shared formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part

On evaluating the xml of sheet3, I found a row like

```
     <x:c r="A79" s="55" t="s">
        <x:v>57</x:v>
     </x:c>
     <x:c r="B79" s="55"/>
     <x:c r="C79" s="56"/>
     <x:c r="D79" s="56"/>
     <x:c r="E79" s="102">
        <x:f t="shared" ref="E78" si="0">SUM(E76)</x:f>
        <x:v>0</x:v>
     </x:c>
  </x:row>
```

After removing " t="shared" ref="E78" si="0" " from the xml the excel is not giving errors anymore.

How can i avoid this error using openxml????

Comment: Include the code in your question ([tag:edit]) that's generating this part of the XML. Since this is a formula, shared text is not appropriate. And the reference is to E76, not E78 so that's an error. You have to find the code that's doing this incorrectly...

Comment: This is an excel generated xml. I am just copying a row from one sheet and adding it to another sheet.

Comment: While that can work in the Excel UI, because Excel is "smart" and adjusts references, this is dangerous when working directly with the file content. As best I can tell, you've taken this row "out of context" so it's missing things to which it's "linked". Read up on the x:f element and what the attributes mean in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellformula(v=office.14).aspx. Then take a look at the XML of the sheet from which you're copying to figure out the relationships. The only way to avoid error like this is to code correctly.

Comment: Can u suggest me a method to copy the entire details in a row to another without disturbing the references

Comment: Excel isn't my specialty, so I'm not that familiar with the Excel OXML SDK object model. I can recognize where problems come from, but haven't enough experience to intuitively know the right way handle the issue. Best I can offer is what I'd try, were I in your position: Analyze the worksheet in Excel to thoroughly understand the content to be copied. Ditto with the "target" range. Then I'd look at where problems could crop up (Refs, "shared", etc.) and work on code to detect and remove them. I'd also ask myself if copying is the right approach - I don't know the WHY of what you're doing...